Store an attribute for each point on a geometry, driven by the scene actual frame
I'm using geometry nodes to create a configurator for one of our products and one of the aims is to be able to tell if any mechanical interference between it and the moving parts exists.
I already created all the node tree to do the calculations and it works ok, it is based on a repeat zone as it has to evaluate each one of 300 points. The problem is that currently, the repeat zone is driven by the scene actual frame so in order to understand if a calculation gives the expected result I have to play the timeline for all the frames from 1 to 300. My need would be to calculate each value separately and save it into the point domain.
What I need to do in the end is:
a) being able to animate the movement afterwards (could be also through python) and stop whenever the calculated value ("Interferenza testa") becomes negative (something which is indicated by the mesh becoming red)
b) extract the index (in the 0-300 range) in which the value becomes negative (through an attribute statistic?) so to present it through value to string or by using python. May also not happen that it becomes negative.
Currently, all the points on my mesh are populated with the same value so in order to understand if it's becoming negative I have to scroll through the timeline, which is not convenient.


Video available here: Video of the current setup

I guess you can try to use a "simulation zone" node. It works similar to the repeat zone, but it works with frame ranges. Maybe you can use the frame number as name for the stored attribute.

Thanks Daniel, I'll try.

I guess I don't understand the question very well... why do you repeat based on the frame number? If you are at frame 30, do you really need frames 1 to 29 to participate in the calculation? Do you really mean 300 points or you mean 300 frames? Why are you iterating frames instead of points?

I started with using frames because the final result will also feature the animation from frames 1 to 300. I thought that I could refer an index for each frame (e.g. index 1 for frame 1, index 2 for frame etc.) and store it in the points domain and then be able to make statistics on them. I'm relatively experienced in blender but totally new to GN and also not that good at python (just bought a course so that hopefully I can get better at it). Most probably it could've been done in Python, but I wanted to make dinner GN practice as well

In addition, should one of the parameters (= mechanical dimensions/sizes) change, I should always be able to recalculate all the points values, so using frames and starting the timeline play seemed a good way to do it

So, could you clarify the objective in the question? Do you need frames or was it just an attempt? If you need frames, does that mean you want to perform the analysis for every animation position? How many values do you need? (300 = 1 per point; or 300 = 1 per frame; or 90000 = 1 per point per frame). Are these 300 points part of an actual geometry or just a dummy geometry to store 300 values? These answers may help a lot to propose a working solution.

I agree, the question is not clear. The title isn't clear, the question body isn't as well, the node tree shows only a small part so it doesn't convey much info. Ideally you would conceptualize the problem, prepare a minimal reproducible example that shows the concept in its purest form, but also describe your actual project to avoid an xy problem

Ok Markus and Daniel, perfectly understood. Here you can find a stripped down blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/18Npx9d7zVfaD2tvUqifMeJwO0QmwpOi3/view?usp=sharing containing the complete node tree.
The aim of this setup (amongst other things) is to calculate the angle at which the gate opener and the leaf collide (provided that it happens). It also calculates the maximum opening angle based on the quotes you can see in the "configuratore battenti" tab in the N panel.

The aim of this setup (amongst other things) is to calculate the angle at which the gate opener and the leaf collide (provided that it happens). It also calculates the maximum opening angle based on the quotes you can see in the "configuratore battenti" tab in the N panel.
What I need is to be able to calculate all the "head interference" values (separately and independently from the play head position), so to understand which is the first one where the "head interference" value becomes negative. This will allow me to show a warning containing the related "opening angle".

E.g. based on the quotes, the maximum opening angle may be 92 degrees. However, just like in the saved example, around 45 degrees the operator and leaf collide. So the maximum opening angle is not 92 degrees anymore, but it will become 45 degrees.
Being able to also animate the resulting movement, just like it's done now with the play function, is a plus and would be very welcome, but I understand that I may have started from the end instead than from the beginning.
